# How to resize the rows so that they always fill the full height of the parent?

Tags: android, resize, android-linearlayout

I have a parent `LinearLayout` with a fixed size. At `onCreate()` I load data and add rows to the parent layout dynamically. Anywhere from 1-10 rows are loaded. I want the rows to always fill the parent, for example if I have 2 rows each row should have 50% height of the parent (50% + 50% = 100%). If I have 3 rows each row should use 33% of the parent height etc.

I tried to use an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to get the height of the parent and resize the rows dynamically, unfortunately when I run the app the resizing is arbitrary at best. Sometimes the rows get resized, sometimes they get resized after a noticeable delay of about 0.5 seconds.

Is there a better way to achieve this? Maybe already in the XML as for example with `layout_weight` (given that the rows only get added in code)?

Comment: Use the layout_weight="1" for each row

Comment: Thanks, this is not possible because the rows themselves are LinearLayouts which do not have this feature. Also I think the weight does not work verticaly though I can be mistaken there.

Comment: It works vertically just depends on the orientation of your parent linearLayout. LinearLayouts do have the weight property. Look up weightSum here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the [weight sum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aweightSum) on the parent LinearLayout to the number of rows you have inside of it. If this is a vertical list of items you would then set the height of each row to 0 and set its [weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight) to 1. If this is a horizontal list of items you do the same but set the width to 0 and set the weight to 1.

Comment: It works even without setting weightSum. The rows get resized correctly after I specify a parent in the inflater. Thank you, I knew there was a simple solution, I guess I am just an idiot at the moment haha :D